# Using three criteria from form three unbound different comboboxs into MS Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am doing access app to deal with my daily job.

As database I have one table and form with three different unbounded comboboxes, subform and report.

For the subform it is ok. I got a filter by whether based on one combobox value or based on two or based on all of them(three).

Now in the report side I made a select query based on the three selected values of the form comboboxes. Once I generate the report with selection on first combobox only it works. If I select second will not change in report, once I selected all of the comboboxes it works and give me the report filtered, the query is with criteria1 or criteria2 or criteria3

```
SELECT CR_2021.ID, CR_2021.CR, CR_2021.REPLAN, CR_2021.[SCH REF], CR_2021.DISC, CR_2021.[REL OF O/H OR POLE REMOVALOR CO/H TO U/GOR REMOVAL OF POLE], CR_2021.CPLANTPOSITION, CR_2021.CC, CR_2021.PASSED, CR_2021.RETURNED, CR_2021.[TOTAL COST], CR_2021.gov, CR_2021.District, CR_2021.BLOCK
FROM CR_2021
GROUP BY CR_2021.ID, CR_2021.CR, CR_2021.REPLAN, CR_2021.[SCH REF], CR_2021.DISC, CR_2021.[REL OF O/H OR POLE REMOVALOR CO/H TO U/GOR REMOVAL OF POLE], CR_2021.CPLANTPOSITION, CR_2021.CC, CR_2021.PASSED, CR_2021.RETURNED, CR_2021.[TOTAL COST], CR_2021.gov, CR_2021.District, CR_2021.BLOCK
HAVING (((CR_2021.gov)=[Forms]![CR_2021_FILTERS]![Area])) OR (((CR_2021.District)=[Forms]![CR_2021_FILTERS]![Dist])) OR (((CR_2021.BLOCK)=[Forms]![CR_2021_FILTERS]![BlockNumber]));
```

Need dynamic report if I select one criteria work ..... etc

Comment: For a dynamic report call  DoCmd.OpenReport from a button or loading form and pass the parameters from your unbound comboboxes in the OpenArgs Property.  One example starts here: http://codevba.com/msaccess/docmd_openreport.htm#.YJEq7cCSnb1

Answer (score 1):

thank you
it is done

```
   Private Sub report_CR_2021_btn_Click()

If IsNull(Area) And IsNull(Dist) And IsNull(BlockNumber) And (Me!PSDCH) Then

DoCmd.OpenReport "CR_2021", acPreview

End If

If IsNull(Dist) Then
    DoCmd.OpenReport "CR_2021", acPreview, , _
    "[gov]='" & Me![Area] & "' OR [district]='" & Me![Dist] & "' OR [block]='" & Me![BlockNumber] & "'"
End If

If IsNull(BlockNumber) Then

        DoCmd.OpenReport "CR_2021", acPreview, , _
    "[gov]='" & Me![Area] & "' AND [district]='" & Me![Dist] & "'"
    Else
DoCmd.OpenReport "CR_2021", acPreview, , _
        "[BLOCK]='" & Me![BlockNumber] & "'"
End If
```